# Mixed vs fixed effects for analysing clustered data where interventions are specified at cluster level but applied to individuals?

Tags: regression, mixed-model

The problem I'm facing is as follows:

There are 42 regions in a health system, each which administers 5 hospitals.

12 of these regions have an active intervention that is applied by all hospitals in the region, to try and reduce readmission rate. I want to assess association of the intervention with readmissions at a point in time.

My mixed effects model specifies the intervention variable (0 vs 1) for individual hospitals, adjusts for fixed effects (continuous and categorical covariables) at individual hospital level, and clusters hospitals into regions allowing for random effects at the region level. Average readmission rate is the outcome variable.

I have concerns that the intervention, as it is designed at the level of regions, might be correlated with any regional random effects, and potentially make the model hard to interpret.

Is this a valid concern (or are there any other issues with my approach). If so, what might be a good alternative method?

Many thanks in advance!!